# Determine the eccentricity of the orbit

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, trajectory, astronomy, astrodynamics

A satellite is in orbit at an altitude of 62.5km, with a speed along the earth-relative position vector of 3.98km/s, and a speed perpendicular to the earth-relative position vector of 7.763km/s. 
What is the eccentricity of its orbit?

Comment: Given those constraints, (and without further acceleration) it is either on an escape vector from Earth, or in a sub-orbital hop to another point on Earth. So since it is 'not in orbit' I'd argue that the question is meaningless.

Comment: homework problem?

Comment: The satellite has been launched from the surface, this is merely a point taken on its trajectory.

Comment: To how many significant figures?

Comment: I've been working with 4 so far

Comment: @AndrewThompson - The magnitude of the velocity vector is 8.72 km/s, less than the  11.1 km/s escape velocity at that altitude. The eccentricity is less than one. This looks like homework, so Carl, it's best if you do this by yourself. Hint: Use the eccentricity vector.

Comment: 62.5 km?!  It won't be in orbit for very long. Also you didn't say if the 3.98 km/s is up or down. (You don't need that sign for the eccentricity.) If it's down, then it _really_ won't be in orbit for very long.

Comment: Ended up using the vis-viva equation along with locating the semimajor axis distance to finally find eccentricity. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AndrewThompson eccentricity has a defined value for both cases you mentioned, so it's not a meaningless question at all.

Answer (score 5):

You should write everything in vector form and then it is just a matter of applying a couple of formulas.

1) Use the given position and velocity values to write the position and velocity vectors, $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$

2) Compute $\vec{h} = \vec{r} \times \vec{v}$ (where $\times$ is the cross product)

3) Compute the eccentricity $\vec{e} = \dfrac{1}{\mu}(\vec{v} \times \vec{h})-\dfrac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|}$